# Конвертация многомерного массива / объекта в формат x-www-form-urlencoded

Tags: javascript, массивы

**Необходимо**

Конвертировать массив вида:

```
[
    {
        a: 1,
        b: [1, 2, 3]
    },
    [
        {
            c: 4,
            d: 5,
            e: [
                6,
                {
                    f:7
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    8
];
```

в объект вида:

```
{
    "name[0][a]": 1,

    "name[0][b][0]": 1,
    "name[0][b][1]": 2,
    "name[0][b][2]": 3,

    "name[1][0][c]": 4,
    "name[1][0][d]": 5,

    "name[1][0][e][0][0]": 6,
    "name[1][0][e][0][1][f]": 7,

    "name[2]": 8,
}
```

*`name` тут чисто для красоты, и может быть использован как один из аргументов на вход для функции-парсера.*

**Что пробовал**

- Гуглить;
- Решить рекурсивно (прокомментировал все строки, ибо страшно):

```js
let processObj = (item, key) => { // наша функция-парсер
  if (item.constructor && item.constructor.name === "Array") { // если массив
    item.forEach((item0, key0) => { //перебираем как массив
      processObj(item0, key0); // обратно вызываем processObj, чтобы "докопться" до обычного значения типа строки или числа
    });
  } else if (item.constructor && item.constructor.name === "Object") { // если объект
    for (let key0 in item) { //перебираем как объект
      processObj(item[key0], key0); // обратно вызываем processObj, чтобы "докопться" до обычного значения типа строки или числа
    }
  } else { // проверки выше не прошли, а значит это число или строка (скорей всего)
    console.log("key", key, "item", item); // просто смотрим, что к нам пришло в аргументах
    return {
      [`[${key}]`]: item
    }; // вот тут и начинаются проблемы. Что сюда нужно писать?
  }
}


let arr = [{"a":1,"b":[1,2,3]},[{"c":4,"d":5,"e":[6,{"f":7}]}],8]; // наш массив 'до'
processObj(arr); // должно вернуть желаемый объект
```

И этот код выглядит логично и успешно проходится по всем элементам и подэлементам достигая конечного ключа и значения (выполнить, для ясности).

**Вопросы**

- Как заставить этот код откладывать "путь" до найденных чисел или строк, чтобы получить желаемого вида объект?
- Изобретаю ли я велосипед? Есть ли в арсенале `js` что-нибудь готовое для парсинга массивов для запроса с данными типа `x-www-form-urlencoded`?

*PS: вариант с `JSON.parse()` не интересен*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let arr = [{"a":1,"b":[1,2,3]},[{"c":4,"d":5,"e":[6,{"f":7}]}],8];

const getType = q => Object.prototype.toString.call(q)

let res = foo(arr)
document.body.innerHTML += `<hr>\n${JSON.stringify(res)} `

function foo(list, props) {
    let { _path = "", res = {} } = props || {}
    for (let key in list) {
        let path = `${_path}['${key}']`
        let val = list[key]
        let typeVal = getType(val)
        if (("[object Array]" === typeVal) || ("[object Object]" === typeVal)) {
            foo(val, { _path: path, res })
        } else {
            let originVal = eval(`arr${path}`)
            let isEq = val === originVal
            document.body.innerHTML += `${JSON.stringify({ path, val, isEq, originVal })} <br>\n`
            res[path] = val
        }
    }
    return res
}
```

Comment: Выглядит круто и читабельно, без особой когнитивной нагрузки, как в моем варианте. Как следствие, в тесте производительности на 1000 итераций и при большей глубине массива выполняется в среднем на `0.02 мс` быстрее (если убрать eval) https://jsfiddle.net/yucse9gm/1/ . Галочка!

Answer (score 3):

Разобрался сам. Комментировать каждую строчку лень поэтому, если возникнут вопросы - задавайте в комментариях - отвечу. Также буду рад кодревью или критике от более опытных js-программистов.

Функция записывается в прототип массива и вызвать ее можно так: `yourArray.parseForRequest([name])`, где `name` - необязательная строка, которая будет лежать в основании имен свойств полученного объекта.

**Актуальность / Новизна**

Посредством этого кода можно отправить многомерный массив на сервер через `x-www-form-urlencoded` и переменная `$_POST` примет подмассивы (если они являются массивами) как массивы, а не как `[object Object]`. Т.е. подмассивы будут доступны как обычно через `$_POST[a][b][c][d]` - понятно.

```js
Array.prototype.parseForRequest = function(name) {
  let parse = (function() {
    let pathStore = {};
    let parser = (item, key, tempPath) => {
      (() => {
        !tempPath && (tempPath = "");

        if (item.constructor && item.constructor.name === "Array") {
          item.forEach((item0, key0) => {
            let currentPath = tempPath + `[${key0}]`;
            parser(item0, key0, currentPath);
          });
        } else if (item.constructor && item.constructor.name === "Object") {
          for (let key0 in item) {
            let currentPath = tempPath + `[${key0}]`;
            parser(item[key0], key0, currentPath);
          }
        } else {
          pathStore[tempPath] = item;
        }
      })();
      return pathStore;
    }
    return parser;
  })();
  return parse(this, null, name);
}


let arr = [{"a":1,"b":[1,2,3]},[{"c":4,"d":5,"e":[6,{"f":7}]}],8];
console.log( arr.parseForRequest("name") ); // поехали
```

Comment: вопрос: зачем тут __!tempPath && (tempPath = "");__ скобки  ?вроде они не нужны.Или нет ?

Comment: @Demon__ANT Без скобок `Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment` т.к. это типа выражение, которое мы хотим выполнить (дословно механику не могу объяснить). Когда мы хотим приравнять значение после `&&` - скобки нужны, но в большинстве других случаев, например, когда мы хотим выполнить функцию, можно обойтись без них.

Comment: спасибо ..очень интересно я про это не знал..